# EBS Payment Gateway implementation in java based technology

Tags: javascript, payment-gateway

Need to implement a payment gateway integrated page in java based technology.

So far I have index.html which gets details of customer info and that is getting redirected to EBS Payment Gateway (as per the code snippet below).

Here goes snippet of index.html page

```
</head>
<body onload="a2()" style="background-color:lightgray; margin-left:300px; margin-right:300px; margin-top:0px;">
    <center>
        <div style="background-color:white;">
              <form action="pay.jsp" method="post" name="frm" id="theForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" autocomplete = "off" />

               <input type="hidden" name="V3URL" value="https://secure.ebs.in/pg/ma/payment/request" />
        <div>

            <h1>EBS - JSP Version 3</h1>
```

///// As a response from the payment gateway following is the code(response.js)  :

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<title>EBS Response</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h2>EBS Response</h2>
<table width="50%" border="1" align="center">
<tr bgcolor="#949494">
<th>Response Parameter Name</th><th>Response Value</th>
</tr>
<%
   Enumeration paramNames = request.getParameterNames();

   while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
      String paramName = (String)paramNames.nextElement();
      out.print("<tr><td>" + paramName + "</td>\n");
      String paramValue = request.getParameter(paramName);
      out.println("<td> " + paramValue + "</td></tr>\n");
   }
%>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

There is Formvalidation code for validating fields of entry

Security is implemented in pay.jsp using MessageDigest of java.(Get noticed the pay.jsp used in 5th line of the index.html snippet)

Now I am stuck to proceed further. What I need is this:

1. the response data has to be updated in MySQL table

2.How to integrate all components to get the full fledged payment gateway

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a POST data coming from response.js.

**1.a.** If you have POST data there is no problem which is look like(it has to be *JSON*):

```
{
  "result" : {
    "ResponseMessage" : "success",
    "TransaactionID": "5555",
    "RequestID" : "8729394"
    .
    .
    .
  }
}
```

**1.b.** If you don't have post data you have to get all params and save to JSON or modal.

**2.** You have to create a Modal for this:

```
public class Result
{
    private string ResponseMessage { get; set; }
    private string TransaactionID { get; set; }
    private string RequestID { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
}

public class RootObject
{
    private Result result { get; set; }
}
```

3. Now you can parse JSON POST Data to your modal then you can use it:

   ```
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   RootObject obj = gson.fromJson(br, DataObject.class);
   System.out.println(obj.getResult().getRequestId());
   ```

You can send these data to `saveOrUpdate(obj);`

Comment: Thanks @hurricane. simple and in right direction. Though I would expect a bit explanation about the Modal part. That would help even better.   And are you suggesting  ResponseMessage{get;set} ...etc as inner classes of "Result" class? What should be passed in setters for RootObject?

Comment: @sumit If you send your post in js data:result it will be like our example. You can console.log (yourPostData) and you can get it in your service. You need to define all params to modal in json.